# Make error while trying to build NDK app

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, cygwin

I'm new to Android programming and NDK, so i've followed this tutorial:
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/ to
install and config cygwin and NDK. The problem appears when I try to execute
ndk-build command. It displays the following error message:

```
$ $NDK/ndk-build
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-18 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 3in ./AndroidManifest.xml
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
install: nie można wykonać stat na `/cygdrive/d/Programowanie/Tools/ADT/NDK/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver': No such file or directory
/cygdrive/d/Programowanie/Tools/ADT/NDK/build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:155: polecenia dla obiektu 'libs/armeabi/gdbserver' nie powiodły się
make: *** [libs/armeabi/gdbserver] Błąd 1
```

Error messages are written in polish so here's my translation, however I'm not sure whether
it's fully correct:

```
$ $NDK/ndk-build
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-18 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 3in ./AndroidManifest.xml
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
install: Cannot execute stat on `/cygdrive/d/Programowanie/Tools/ADT/NDK/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver': No such file or directory
/cygdrive/d/Programowanie/Tools/ADT/NDK/build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:155: commands for object 'libs/armeabi/gdbserver' didn't succeed.
make: *** [libs/armeabi/gdbserver] Error 1
```

I honestly have no idea what could have caused such an error, so I'm counting that 
You can help me anyhow.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern versions of NDK do not need cygwin. Try to run you build from normal cmd prompt. To be on the safe side, remove `cygwin\bin` from PATH.

Comment: I tried to do as you said, however command "ndk-build" was not recognized as a command or application by windows command line.
Plus what I found on NDK's website: "For Windows, Cygwin 1.7 or higher is required. The NDK will not work with Cygwin 1.5 installations.", so i guess cygwin is still required.

Comment: If you look at rev. 7 notes, "You can now build your NDK source files on Windows without Cygwin by calling the ndk-build.cmd script from the command line from your project path. The script takes exactly the same arguments as the original ndk-build script. The Windows NDK package comes with its own prebuilt binaries for GNU Make, Awk and other tools required by the build. You should not need to install anything else to get a working build system."

Comment: Check that there is `ndk-build.cmd` file in the root directory of your NDK installation `d:\Programowanie\Tools\ADT\NDK`

Comment: Hm, what i found in my NDK directory is a file ndk-build without any extension, so i opened it with notepad and it contains a bash script which for what i know doesn't work on Windows, could it be because I have downloaded some older version of NDK?

Comment: Edit: The downloaded package with NDK should also contain doc folder, which is absent inside my NDK directory, maybe that's
a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue with NDK by downloading it again and reinstalling.
It seems like I haven't downloaded entire NDK package, and that it caused 
the problem. Sorry for trouble, I should have checked whether reinstall 
could help in this case on the beginning, but this idea must have slept 
my mind.

Thanks for letting me know that I don't need cygwin for NDK anymore :-)

Best regards, Buyuk.